# Part::pspec error occured

Tags: warning-messages

I wanted to simulate a noise model on CCD sensors, so I did as below:

```
noise[i_, j_] := RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[50], {20, 20}][[i, j]];
noiseimage = DiscretePlot3D[noise[i, j], {i, 1, 20, 1}, {j, 1, 20, 1}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

Then I got an error message "Part::pspec" but the desired image appeared.
What was wrong with my code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Works without error for me on V10.4.1. Have you tried on a fresh kernel to avoid problems with previous assignments?

Comment: @YvesKlett I was working on Mathematica 9.0. I've refreshed the kernel before executing the above commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simulating new values everytime you call `noise[_,_]`. To simulate once and plot that you could rewrite it as:

```
(noise[i_, j_] = #[[i, j]]) &[RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[50], {20, 20}]];
noiseimage = DiscretePlot3D[noise[i, j], {i, 1, 20, 1}, {j, 1, 20, 1}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

The error message concerning the symbolic part argument is not really an error, just a warning.

Comment: I understood your code but arose a question that why you used the pure function `#`. I thought just eliminating the colon `:` before the equal sign `=` in the definition of `noise[_,_]` is easier and sufficient, i.e. `noise[i_, j_] = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[50], {20, 20}][[i, j]];`  Did I miss something important concepts to write Mathematica codes?

Comment: @TaikiBessho You are right, the pure function is only needed when using `:=`.

Comment: I tried your command above in my Mathematica(ver.9) but I got the error message again... Then, I wonder how should I do for not getting the error message...

Comment: Or I don't have to mind the error?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and faster is:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[50], {20, 20}]]
```

Comment: Yeah, it might be useful for some people.  I, however, want to get the noise levels not in grayscale but in heights of rectangular blocks. Anyway, thank you.